How to obtain the OIDC access token in Blazor with .NET 8
I have a Blazor .NET8 app with OIDC and interactive server mode; the configuration in Program.cs is:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

which means that user authentication happens before any page is entered.
I'd like to call a Sharepoint API and my understanding is that that requires an access token:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uploadUrl) 
// ...
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

My question is: how can I obtain token ? I have tried the following code in a Razor page:
var authState = await ASP.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var token = authState.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "access_token")?.Value;

however token always comes back as null;  and for debugging purposes I printed out all the Type in the claims principal and none of them resembled an access token.
I also tried AddBearerToken() as described in New in .NET 8 but that made no difference.
I have reviewed the pages linked from How to get access token claims in a Blazor Server app using OIDC? but none of them talk about access_token as a claim.

I followed this case to integrate AAD authentication into my .Net 8 blazor web app server side rendered project. Using codes below so that we could use ITokenAcquisition service to generate access token.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Here's my test result
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject ITokenAcquisition TokenAcquisitionService

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var token = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read" });
        var token2 = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://client_id/Tiny.Greet" });
    }
}



What string would I use in GetAccessTokenForUserAsync  for the use case in my question (calling SharePoint API via HttpRequest)

Hi @MM could you please let me know which SharePoint API you wanna call? Or which API permission was already consent to your AAD application? For example, you want to call this API, then let's see the API permission, we should grant Sites.Read.All in AAD. I mean it depends on the API document.

I'd like to either allow user to upload a file, or createa folder (whichever's easier)

upload small files api -> /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content. Create folder api: /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children Could you please try these 2 apis and see whether they meet your requirement or not?

are you saying to make a HttpRequest using URLs with those strings, as in my question ?

thank you for your reply, please try with my codes above and you will get access token, then you can try to call the api with postman or some other tools and see whether you could call the api successfully and whether the api is what you want.
